# A good book for the p-fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can anyone suggest an article for the p-fractional Laplacian for beginners. I am interested in the regularity of weak solution of the following equation
$$(- \Delta)_{p}^s u  = f(u)\quad \text{in }  \Omega, u=0 \quad \text{in }  \mathbb R^N\setminus \Omega,$$ where $s\in (0,1), p>1$ and $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain.